# Find Max and add it to the Array using heap

Tags: arrays, mips, heap

I have problem with my code because it said:
Runtime exception at 0x00400084: address out of range 0x00000050 and I try to debug and look at my code again, but I dont know where is the mistake.
My code is compare each pair of elements of 2 array and add the larger to the new array.
It requires to use heap in this code too.
The problem happens at the line

```
l.d $f0, ($a0) #load double from Arr1
```

```
.eqv ALLOC_MEM 9

.data
Arr1: .double 3.2, 8.6, 9.1, 15.2, -3.8, 21.8
Arr1Sz: .space 64
Arr1Count: .space 6

Arr2: .double -3.5, 6.2, 18.0,  7.3, -5.2, 35.6
Arr2Sz: .space 64
Arr2Count: .space 6

MaxArr: .space  64
MaxSz: .space 64
MaxCount: .space 6
.text
main:
    #Array 1
    #Calculate the size of the array in bytes 
    la $a0, Arr1
    la $t1, Arr1Sz
    sub $t2, $t1, $a0
    sw $t2, Arr1Sz #size in byte
    #Calculate the number of elements
    div $t1, $t2, 8
    sw $t1, Arr1Count #number of elements

    #Array 2
    #Calculate the size of the array in bytes 
    la $a1, Arr2
    la $t3, Arr2Sz
    sub $t4, $t3, $a1
    sw $t4, Arr2Sz #size in byte
    #Calculate the number of elements
    div $t3, $t4, 8
    sw $t3, Arr1Count #number of elements

    #Copy the array to the heap
    li $v0, ALLOC_MEM
    li $a0, 64
    syscall
    li $t0, 0 #loop counter

    jal MaxArray

    move $a2, $v0 #Max array address
    move $a3, $t0 #Number of element

    jal PrintArray

MaxArray:
Loop: 
    beq $t0,$t1,Continue
    l.d $f0, ($a0) #load double from Arr1
    l.d $f2, ($a1) #load double from Arr2
    c.eq.s $f0, $f2
    bc1f else
    s.d $f2, ($v0)
    j increase
else:   
    s.d $f0, ($v0)
increase:
    #increase index of array
    addi $a0, $a0, 8
    addi $a1, $a1, 8
    #increase address of the heap
    addi $v0, $v0, 8
    #increase counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    b Loop
Continue:
    jr $ra
PrintArray:
    li $t5, 0 #loop counter for print array
PrintLoop:
    bge $t5, $a3, exit
    l.d $f2, 0($a2)
    addi $a2, $a2, 8
    #print double 
    li $v0, 3
    mov.d $f12, $f2
    #increment counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j PrintLoop
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that there is a problem, as the processor has taken an exception.  However, you cannot be entirely sure where the actual problem is.

You need to be able to look at data values and see which ones make sense and which ones don't.  For the default memory model, 0x50 is a bad address for either code or data.

You can debug this forwards or backwards, but the job is to find out why the program is attempting to use 0x50, and who (some earlier instruction sequence) provided that bad address.

Working forwards, if a small program, is probably best, so just single step and check the results of each instruction.  On MIPS with a normal memory configuration, data will be located around address 0x10010000, and so obviously a value of 0x50 is much too small.

Working backwards, you can put a breakpoint at earlier and earlier instructions (or use backwards single step from the failure).

I prefer going forwards for most small programs, single stepping to verify each instruction is doing what is expected of it — verify each data value produced — because the first divergence is the best place to start, and fixing that may eliminate subsequent problems.  When going backwards, you're working on a specific issue but that may have been caused by an earlier error that the processor didn't catch.

Specifically, you want to find out who put 0x50 in `$a0` as that is a bad address to use to dereference that pointer.